# PrimaryKeyRelatedField does not serialize the object

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have a game model like this:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    ...
```

And a serializer like this:

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "description",
            "owner"
        )
```

When I make a request I get this:

```
description: "TestDescription"
name: "TestName"
owner: 1
```

I was expecting `owner` to be a dictionary with fields like an `email`, a `username` and so forth. What is wrrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrimaryKeyRelatedField` will only give you the primary key (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield), not a `dict`. What you want to do is to define:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "first_name", "last_name")
```

And use that in `GameSerializer`:

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ("id", "name", "description", "owner")

    owner = UserSerializer()
```